# Extract numbers from decimal list

Tags: python-3.x, django-views

I searched around not found suitable answers, maybe a simple question but really stop me forward:

`aList = [Decimal('-1.23'), Decimal('4.56')]`

how to extract only the numbers: `['-1.23', '4.56']`?

any better methods than using split or re.findall()

Many thanks!

Comment: Your sample output shows strings that have been wrapped in numbers, not the numbers. Converting it to a float would also result in rounding errors.

Comment: Yeppi, you know exactly I want ! Not strings but numbers [1.23, 3.45]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`str(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) to get a textual presentation of the decimal, for example:

```
>>> [str(a) for a in aList]
['-1.23', '4.56']
```

Now these are strings.

You can furthermore use [**`float(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-float) to convert it to the nearest representable floating point number:

```
>>> [float(a) for a in aList]
[-1.23, 4.56]
```

Comment: Many thanks! you know exactly what I want:-) Now I use directly `[float(str(a)) for a in aList]`, thanks for the clean and tidy answer!

Comment: @NegaOverflow: `[float(a) for a in aList]` can do the trick as well with the original list.

Comment: I was thinking that also, hesitate to try.... what a fantastic Python, full of tricks to learn ;-)

Comment: In fact I should have done this: `aList = [float(x.value) for x in model.objects.all]` ;-)